# Manga where the girl travels back to feudal Japan with a katana and finds the original owner of the sword with another one

Tags: story-identification, manga

The girl MC went back in time to feudal Japan for some reason. After surviving outside for a bit, she finds a group of people; one of them happened to be the owner of the heirloom sword she was transported with.

The guy (Nobunaga, I think) asked why his sword is in the girls possession, and why is it so badly maintained.

There was also this other guy that looked eerily like the girl's younger brother.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: "After surviving outside for a bit" - does this mean wilderness survival, i.e. not immediately running into groups of soldiers? Do you recall about how many chapters it takes for her to find others? Most/all of the examples I'm finding involve the girl getting involved with one group of soldiers or another immediately.

Comment: my memory is very hazy since it was a long time ago, but those are the only things i remember sadly, although i think it was 1 or 2 chapters before the girl found them, the girls also hated killing, im sorry that i cannot bring any more info, i am currently racking my brain seeing if i can remember something

Comment: I'd suggest going to mangaupdates.com and doing an advanced search for the tags "Time Travel" and either "Nobunaga or a Relative" or "Sengoku Era" and see if you recognize any of the descriptions or covers. There aren't many results for either search, but all the ones I've looked at haven't included the sword scene.